# Do Redux selectors cause unnecessary component renders?

Tags: redux, selector

From what I've understood from Dan Abramov's egghead video 'javascript-redux-colocating-selectors-with-reducers' and some of his tweets, it is a good practice to use a selector to map the state to a prop and remove this logic from the Component and placing it in the Reducer (where the state is managed).

Although this makes all the sense, it also causes my component to render everytime a new state is added to the store, even when only a non related property of the state object was changed. Is there a way to overcome this without using reselectors, which might be a bit overkill for the simpler cases?

Comment: I'm assuming you've eliminated `shouldComponentUpdate`, but why?

Comment: I would prefer not to use it, since it would require comparing table rows.

Comment: How are you using the `connect()` binding from `react-redux`? Make sure you're only mapping the data you need.

Comment: In the video I've mentioned and in several tutorials, the whole store is passed to the selector in mapStateToProps(), so the component is totally independent of the store structure. That's why I get unnecessary re-renders when changes occur in other (unrelated) parts of the state tree.

Answer (score 3):

As you may know, `mapStateToProps` is called every time your store is updated.

Whether the component will re-render depends on what `mapStateToProps` returns. (Actually, it depends on the combined props object returned by `mapStateToProps` *and* `mapDispatchToProps`.)

React Redux (the library that provides the `connect` function) makes a shallow equality check on the returned object and the *last* returned object. If the equality check succeeds (i.e. the previously returned object is determined to be equal to the next returned object), the component will not re-render. If the check fails, the component will re-render.

For example, let's say you always return the following object from `mapStateToProps`:

```
{
  items: [],
}
```

This object will never be equal to itself (`[] === []` returns `false` because they're different arrays). The equality check will thus fail and the component will re-render.

However, React Redux performs a more complex equality check that that (the implementation of its `shallowEqual` function can be found [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/utils/shallowEqual.js)).

For example, even though `{ a: 'b' } === { a: 'b'}` returns `false` (they're different objects), `shallowEqual` *will* pass them off as equal. This is because `shallowEqual` will compare each key of the returned object with each key of the previously returned object, but only *one* level deep. More details can be found in the implementation I linked to above.

**In summary**, if you don't want your component to re-render, you'll need to make sure that the equality check succeeds.

You can:

- Save the returned object into the state using a reducer
- Cache the result using Reselect
- Implement `shouldComponentUpdate` in the component by hand

These suggestions come straight from Redux's FAQ page: https://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-rendering-too-often

You can also make sure your `mapStateToProps` function returns objects that are considered equal by `shallowEqual` (e.g. objects without arrays, and only one level deep).

For simplicity, I would opt for Reselect.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: No it is not.

But there is common mistake that causes unnecessary renders of components when you're using selectors. You should always make sure to define your selector once. So what does it mean?

When you are using **connect** method, you can pass **mapStateToProps** method as an argument. Object returned by this method will be passed as props to your component and if you define your selector inside this object it will be redefined each time your component receives a prop. Here is an example for that:

Defining your selector like this could cause your component to render unnecessarily. This is because each time you pass a prop to your component you're basically redefining **getSettings** method.

```
@connect(state => ({
  getSettings: ()=>'sample output',
}))
class Sample extends React.Component {}
```

Correct way is the define your selector like this, so that it'll be only created once and the reference passes through your **mapStateToProps** argument.

```
const getSettings = () =>'sample output';
@connect(state => ({
  getSettings,
}))
class Sample extends React.Component {}
```

Comment: Why in the world are you passing the selector into the component as a prop instead of using the selector in selecting the data, and then pass the data? The way it's shown here complicates the component by having it execute the selector first.